# asp.net membership get login name

Tags: asp.net, membership

i see i can call Request.IsAuthenticated but how do i get the login name from asp.net membership provider once i am logged in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a number of mechanisms to get the currently logged on user's name, for example, you can get to it via the context of the current web page like so:

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

However, usually the best way to get the current user's name is via the context of the current Http request like so:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Ultimately, you're calling down into the same "User" object, and accessing the same [System.Security.Principal.IIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx) object instance in either case, but using the HttpContext allows this code to be used not only in web pages but also ASP.NET user controls and [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) classes etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Request.LogonUserIdentity
```